# write(in file) only the last data in LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, filewriter

I am trying to write a file called movie.txt but unfortunately it only stored the last one in the LinkedList. What should I use to actually make it store all of them by line because I need it as input file after this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;

public class movie508
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        LinkedList listMovie = new LinkedList();
        int size = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter number of movie: "));
        Movie m;

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter name : ");
            int b = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter year : "));
            String c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter LPF rating : ");
            int d = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter time"));
            String e = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter genre : ");
            double f = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter member rating : "));

            m = new Movie(a, b, c, d, e, f);
            listMovie.insertAtFront(m);
        }

        Object data = listMovie.getFirst();
        PrintWriter out = null;

        while(data != null)
        {
            m = (Movie)data;

            try {

                out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("movie.txt"));
                out.write(m.toString());
            } 
            finally 
            {
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }
            data = listMovie.getNext();
        }

    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reopening the file, and thus overwriting it, in each iteration of the `while` loop. Open it once before the loop, and close it at it's end:

```
PrintWriter out = null;
try {
    out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("movie.txt"));
    while(data != null) {
        m = (Movie)data;
        out.println(m.toString());
        data = listMovie.getNext();
    }
} 
finally {
    if (out != null) {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to add new line after each data but the error is newline has private access to java.io.printwriter. how can i add new line?

Comment: Just use [`println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(java.lang.String)) instead of write - edited in to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
In java FileWriter api is as below:

public FileWriter(String fileName,
          boolean append)
           throws IOException
Constructs a FileWriter object given a file name with a boolean indicating whether or not to append the data written.
Parameters:
fileName - String The system-dependent filename.
append - boolean if true, then data will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning. 
Throws: 
IOException - if the named file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason.

So if you want to append just make the append parameter true as below:

out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("movie.txt",true));

This will append the text to existing file instead of over writing.
```